# What are some good books for vlsi cmos design? Or some good educational software?

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

I'm a student trying to learn more about CMOS design, I already understand assembly and computer architecture, but VLSI is very interesting and I was wondering if you guys knew some good books/games in order to learn more. I already know how to use electric, and I just want to know more about this topic. Also, I don't know if this question is suited for this exchange specifically, but if there would be a better place to ask please let me know.

Comment: Over at the EE StackExchange: [VLSI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/vlsi/info), [C-MOS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/cmos/info).